# Django skips particular migration(No Migrations to apply)

Tags: python, django, migration, python-3.5, migrate

I am working on an app at Django 1.9

I created altered one field from `User` model (max_length to 120 from 40).
I know the migration has not run and i can see that it is skipped obviously. 
I can't seem to understand why this is happening.

I made sure that the dependencies are in place as well.

Things i tried:

1- Verified that the database does not say it as run(django_migrations table):
See there is no `0021_alter_user_lms_user_id`

[image: django_migrations table]

2- i check if django is able to see migration file:

[image: django showmigrations command result]

I am very surprised with this outcome.
I cannot purge my migrations nor the database because this is a deployed app with data.

Any help is appreciated

Note: I checked all related questions i could find before posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it myself and hoping this helps others experiencing same or similar issue with Django.

It seems like ***Django does not just check whether a migration has run by file name but also it pays attention on the order of the file by the leading numbers in filenames***(At least in my experience).

History of steps:

**git branch a**: creates migrations for `0021_alter_user_lms_user_id` and has not been merged into master yet.

**git branch b**:  created migration for `0022_toolconsumer_is_vericite_enabled` (thinking i should follow the order and manually prefix file name with `0022_`)

Now at this point i merge **git branch b** into master and run migrations.
So now when i merge **git branch a** into master and want to run migrations, django sees file but since `0022_` is supposingly after `0021_`, skips the file instead actually checking whether it is applied to db.

**Fix:** I basically renamed file name from `0021_alter_user_lms_user_id` to `0023_alter_user_lms_user_id`(don't forget to update dependencies ) and ran `./manage.py migrate` and worked with no issues. See the image.

[image: working migration result screen capture]

Hope this helps somebody.